# Why am I not given the option to answer this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, answers

I was having an issue and found a question that matched it:
[Whatsapp Web: "Phone Not Connected"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87858/whatsapp-web-phone-not-connected)

However, I've now solved this issue on the newest version of Android and would like to post my answer. But when I scroll to the bottom of the page there is no answer box. The answer box shows up on other webapps questions. What's going on here and why am I not allowed to answer the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question was autoprotected by the system for having 3 spam/non-answer posts added to it back in 2017. The reason the answer box wasn't available was that the system requires you to have 10 reputation on a site ([reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user), this does not include your association bonus) to answer a protected question.

That being said, there's no reason to continue to protect it, so I have unprotected it.  Thanks for adding your answer.

Comment: Just realised the detail you've included in brackets is somewhat hidden away.  "Once you’ve earned 10 reputation points *from participating on this site*."  Guess I'll just have to find some questions to post answers to....